# Meaning in context: 'I was' or 'I have been'

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, difference

What is correct in this context?
'Have you ever been to Italy?' 
->'Yes,  I was last year.'
OR
->'Yes, I have been last year.'

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a specific time expression like " last year", you have to use past simple. Have you ever been to Italy? Yes, I went last year. Where were you in July last year? I was in Italy.

Comment: Actually, even though you're right, (though I'm not sure what you mean by *definition of time*; you'd do well to rephrase that) people utter such things. E.g., *Have you ever been to Italy?* ~ *Yes, I have – last year, actually.*, or just ~ *I have – last year.* Of course, I punctuated it differently and that's pretty much the only way that utterance can be legit.